# Changing the Firebase Cloud rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rules in my Firebase Cloud database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting emails saying that:

> We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
>
> - any user can read your entire database
> - any user can write to your entire database

In our main screen, user can enter the app only by signing with email + password or with his phone number + code that he gets via SMS. Both work with the Firebase auth serivce. What should be the rules in that case?

Comment: In order to write effective rules, they must be paired with specific specific queries that should be allowed or denied by the rules.  Without seeing queries, there's no way how to write a rule that implement the desired security.  Please edit the question to be more clear about the query are you working with.  I suggest also starting with the documentation to learn how rules work: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to allow access to authenticated users, you would modify your rules as follows:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Having said that, note the following two points:

- By doing `/{document=**}` (i.e. using [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards)) you apply these rules to all the collections/document of the Firestore database. It may be better to explicitly define the rules for each collection, in order to control the access to each collection in a more fine-grained manner. This way, you avoid any mistake in the future where you create a new non-public collection but forget to adapt the security rules.
- Do not forget that anyone that has the Web API Key of your Firebase project (which is not difficult to find in the source code of your app) can create an account to your Firebase project, for example with a simple call to the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password). In other words, this rule only allows authenticated users to access your DB, but, by default, anyone can become an authenticated user.

Comment: In the sign up activity, it contains an option "Group" which user should chose an existing group. The group names are stored in the database `/groups/<group-name>`. I guess that with those rules it won't work right? Because it could not fetch this information. Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: Ooh, indeed this totally changes the situation!! You need to give more details on what you want to do with this groups collection. Do you want to check if the user belongs to a group?

Comment: Sorry! no, just to fetch all groups and each user can try to "sign up" to that group but it will work only if he has permissions to that group (added by another member).

Comment: It seems that this should be a totally new question. Please write a new question with all the details of your exact goal. You may accept and/or upvote my current answer if you think it answers your original question (i.e. how to solve the fact that you are getting alert emails about your rules)